# How to convert a Mat variable type in an IplImage variable type in OpenCV 2.0?

Tags: opencv, iplimage

I am trying to rotate an image in OpenCV.

I've used this code that I found here on Stack Overflow:

```
Mat source(img);
Point2f src_center(source.cols/2.0, source.rows/2.0);
Mat rot_mat = getRotationMatrix2D(src_center, 40.0, 1.0);
Mat dst;
warpAffine(source, dst, rot_mat, source.size());
```

Once I have my `dst` `Mat` variable type filled up I would like to put it back to an `IplImage` variable type, any idea about how to do this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In the new OpenCV 2.0 C++ interface it's not really necessary to change from back and forth between `Mat` and `IplImage`, but if you want to you can use the `IplImage` operator:

```
IplImage dst_img = dst;
```

Note that only the IplImage header is created and the data (pixels) will be shared.  For more info see the  [OpenCV C++ interface](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/c++_cheatsheet.html) or the `image.cpp` example in the `OpenCV-2.0/samples/c` directory.

Comment: Thank you very much ! It did work ! Didn't think we could manage it like this.

Comment: This did not work for me but the first one by @lumapu worked for me fine where image data is copied directly

Answer (score 15):

For having the whole `IplImage` object, I've used this code:

```c
Mat matImage;
IplImage* iplImage;

iplImage = cvCreateImage(cvSize(640,480), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
iplImage->imageData = (char *) matImage.data;
```

You can also copy the data instead of pointer:

```c
memcpy(iplImage->imageData, matimage.data, 640*480);
```

Answer (score 1):

Norman in [his blog](http://wangpengnorman.blogspot.com/2009/06/transform-between-cvmat-and-iplimage.html) describes the following (Although it is not 2.0, it should apply to your problem.):

To transform from CvMat to IplImage, Use function:

```
IplImage* cvGetImage( const CvArr* arr, IplImage* image_header );
```

The function cvGetImage returns image header for the input array that can be matrix - CvMat*, or image - IplImage*.
In the case of image the function simply returns the input pointer.
In the case of CvMat* it initializes image_header structure with parameters of the input matrix.
Usage:

```
IplImage stub, *dst_img;
dst_img = cvGetImage(src_mat, &stub);
```

Answer (score 0):

In later versions of OpenCV 2.4 and above, we can convert it simply by

```
cv::Mat inMat;
//do the stuffs
IplImage* outIPL = (IplImage*)(&IplImage(inMat));
```