# How to convert from c++ interface cv::Mat to c IplImage?

Tags: c++, c, opencv, detect

How to convert from c++ interface cv::Mat  to c IplImage ?
such that i used

*IplImage * lpl= matimage;*

and matimage contain data and after some operation i want to do inverse convert.
from IplImage* lpl ===> cv::Mat 
can i use a copy data and how ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert a Mat variable type in an IplImage variable type in OpenCV 2.0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2468307/how-to-convert-a-mat-variable-type-in-an-iplimage-variable-type-in-opencv-2-0)

Answer (score 2):

```
cv::Mat img = ....;
IplImage iplImg = img;
```

Then

```
cv::Mat img2(iplImg);
```

Comment: @rotating_image I'n not sure I follow. Assigning an image to a pointer doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include "iostream"
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    Mat image = imread("C:\\lena.jpg");
    IplImage image2 = image;
    cvShowImage("TESTiplimage",&image2);
    imshow("TESTmat",image);
    waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

...try this code it...it works for me...you should get 2 windows showing the same image..