# Extract the objects from image using IplImage

Tags: opencv, detect

How can i extract the objects from an image using `IplImage`?

Also, how can I get the original color of the object if I have the mask with white pixels where the object is?

An example of what I want to do can be found [here](http://bsd-noobz.com/opencv-guide/60-2-color-based-object-segmentation), but using `IplImage` not `mat`.

Comment: Ok, what have you tried?

Comment: Since the link you provide already has code for what you want to do, why don't you use that, and convert to IplImage based on the [other question you asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12355547/how-to-convert-from-c-interface-cvmat-to-c-iplimage)?